# Change heroku repo when doing 'git push heroku master'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

I just started learning this stuff and I messed up my database (did heroku run rake twice and had double of everything) so I figured I'd delete (again since I just started I thought I could just reupload my entire directory to start a new heroku app) the app from my Heroku and start again. I do `heroku create` and that worked fine and gives me a new address, but now when I do `git push heroku create` I get

```
remote: !       No such app as <OLD ADDRESS>.
fatal: repository 'https://git.heroku.com/<OLD ADDRESS>.git/' not found
```

how do I change this so that it looks for the new address it just gave me in the second `heroku create`?

Comment: check out https://www.railstutorial.org/book/beginning#sec-heroku_commands which mentions the `heroku rename <new-app-name>' command

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question.  "how do I change this so that it looks for the new address it just gave me in the second heroku create?"  So that what looks for the new address?